# query with values distinct, mysql, django

Tags: mysql, django-orm

I have model with users, questions and answers. Now I want to display questions, which user replied.

I am writing this in views.py:

```
    answers = Answer.objects.filter(author__username=user.username)[:5]
```

and this in a template:

```
{% for answer in answers %}
{{ answer.question.head }} <hr>
{% endfor %}
```

And I see 2 questions repeated 5 times with hr line in the end. I want to see 2 questions, even if the user replied 5 times to 2 answers, so I try this:

```
    answers = Answer.objects.filter(author__username=user.username).values('question__head').distinct()[:5]
```

But when I open my page I see just two hr lines and no content for some reason.
I tried ORM and it works properly

```
>>> Answer.objects.filter(author__pk=2).values('question__head').distinct()
[{'question__head': u'question1?'}, {'question__head': u'question2?'}]
```

Why does {{ answer.question.head }} not work in template anymore after adding the distinct condition?

Comment: Do `mysql` support `distinct()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, finally I solved it with the following pieces of code:

```
#views.py
answers = Answer.objects.filter(author__username=user.username).values_list('question__head', flat=True).distinct()[:5]

#template
{% for answer in answers %}
{{answer}}
{% endfor %}
```